# How to count the number of occurrence in a column in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables:

> Table A(Column1a, Column2a, Column3a);
>
> Table B(Column1b);

Column1b values can be 0,1,2,3,4 or 5.

I want to count the number of 0,1,2,3 values in Column1b then store it in Column1a.

Column2a value will be the count of Column1b where the value is 1.

Column3a value will be the count of Column1b where the value is 2 or 3.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_a (Column1a, Column2a, Column3a)
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Column1b IN (0,1,2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Column1b = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
 SUM(CASE WHEN Column1b IN (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table_b
```